# Android Navigation Drawer - Call Base Content View

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I wanted to know how to call the base **content_main.xml** (layout) from the Navigation Drawer after calling other **FragmentActivity.class**, wherein the **content_main.xml** is the first view you'll see on starting the android application.

I can't do this because I think the Main Activity (**MainActivity_Fragment.class**) along with the NavigationDrawer extends **AppCompatActivity**...  If you need a code I'll just display the code snippets... since the code too long.

If there's a way to call the default contentview, let me know... I searched google many times and unfortunately no answers... Please Help, thank you...

**MainActivity_Fragment.class**

```
public class MainActivity_Fragment extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
    SlideFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    View.OnClickListener{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
}
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
...
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        //startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity_Fragment.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        MainActivity_Fragment newFragment = new MainActivity_Fragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.activity_translator, newFragment); // THIS IS THE ERROR WHEREIN MAINACTIVITY.CLASS SHOULD IMPLEMENT FRAGMENT
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
...
}
```

And this is my **content_main.xml** layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_for_Fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/card_activity_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

...// MY DEFAULT DISPLAY CONTENT

</LinearLayout>
```

Platform: Android Studio 2.2 Preview 5

Android SDK Target: 24

Min 15

**NOTE**: I didn't used **FragmentActivity** as extension of my Class, I simply used **AppCompatActivity**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, I think it's in my own Activity, I should have re-code my `MainActivity_Fragment.class` and extend it to `FragmentActivity`.
But I'm still looking forward for the answer to not migrate to `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this may be helpful to you just change the bellow line

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

To

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Sill got error on the same line


`transaction.replace(R.id.activity_translator, newFragment);`

Comment: can u give me the name of eroor

Comment: `Error:C:\...\MainActivity_Fragment.java:306: error: incompatible types: MainActivity_Fragment cannot be converted to Fragment
            transaction.replace(R.id.activity_translator, newFragment);
                                                          ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error`

Comment: check your fragment it must be **import android.support.v4.app.Fragment** not   **android.app.Fragment**

Comment: I imported `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;` to work with **FragmentTransaction** you suggest.

Comment: Check your import section of **MainActivity_Fragment** class and check which fragment u use

Comment: Yes Sir, I used the `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`... but still... Sorry.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.activity_translator, new MainActivity_Fragment());

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'add(int, .MainActivity_Fragment())'`

Comment: clean and rebuild your project and add the commit() at the end of last statement

Comment: same error sir, I think my MainActivity should extend **FragmentActivity** instead of **AppCompatActivity**?

Comment: yup its must require

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate() of MainActivity_Fragment, the first view should be default fragment like this:

```
            mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            //Default fragment when begin
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, homeFragment);
            mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: May I know Sir the declaration type of `fragobj` ?

Comment: Ah, Edited my post, please check